# Windows shuts down unexpectedly when waking up from sleep

Tags: windows-7, crash, sleep, shutdown

I've been facing this issue since yesterday, whenever I put the computer into sleep mode and when I wake up, it takes me to boot menu with choices; start Windows normally, safe mode, etc. in short, it shuts down unexpectedly while waking up. I have my laptop dual booted with up-to-date Windows 7 SP1 (32-bit) and Ubuntu 10.10. This problem is not happening with Ubuntu.

I googled the issue and went through [this](http://social.technet.Microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproperf/thread/c1b5cbfe-025d-4e61-8162-baebf0483519), [this](http://windows7forums.com/Windows-7-support/47821-Windows-7-shuts-down-instead-sleep.HTML) and [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/exiting-sleep-mode-causes-shut-down) page. But, none of the threads were helpful to solve it. I've found that there's something to do with device drivers. What can be done to resolve the issue? Can SFC utility solve it if it is due to corrupt system files?

Comment: do you have hybrid sleep on?-advanced power options->sleep->hybrid sleep to 'off'.

Comment: @mic84: No, its just a normal sleep mode.

Comment: I recall I saw a hotfix for this somewhere...

Comment: It sucks having a Windows box when this sort of problem occurs.

Comment: (You might want to check Task Scheduler for any tasks that run "on unlock" or some such.)

Comment: Anything in the event log?

Answer (score 1):

There are many out there with the same or close to the same problem, this is what i found, should you wish to try.(i could not find any new Microsoft hotfixes for this problem)

- Have you installed any software that may have changed your settings?
- Does anything show in reliability monitor?
- Are there any errors or warnings in the Event Log?
- Have you tried disabling **hybrid sleep** in Advanced Power Options?
- Is it possible that your computer is set to hibernate after a certain amount of time?
- Have you tried turning off hibernate?
- Are there any updates to your BIOS firmware?
- Uninstall any third-party antivirus/firewall software
- If you're overclocking, reset values to normal
- Go to manufactures website and download and install all drivers from there
- Run the Memory Diagnostic & HD Diagnostic,
- Run System File Checker:

  - Start > Run > CMD > Right Click and Run as administrator
  - Type in `SFC /SCANNOW`
- Run startup repair
- Run a system image restore
- Run a system restore, this will change your registry back to how it was before.
- Reinstall Windows

Comment: I had fun reading your list  :) Run the Memory Diagnostic & HD Diagnostic +1

Answer (score 0):

Your memory or permanent storage is behaving oddly, causing Windows' hibernate procedure to choke? Run the SFC utility after scanning your drive and memory for errors (use intuiton... how old is the computer?).

e.g.

```
chkdisk
memtest86+
```

---

If you know that your box is not broken or dying; allocate more "swap". Increase the size of your "pagefile" to about (at least) 50% of your memory (again use intuiton ...how much RAM does your box use while fully operational?).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was solved after disabling the **Fast Startup** on Power Options.

I just followed the "Method 2" of the answer in this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/pc-shuts-down-a-while-after-waking-up-from-sleep/10b1e201-5237-49f0-b1b6-04eba405ef0d

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1198283)